# MPI.NET Send/ImmediateProbe not working when using multiple hosts

Tags: c#, mpi, message-passing

I developed an MPI test program where the master node distributes work to the worker nodes.
The worker node uses `comm.Send()` to request work and the master node checks with `comm.ImmediateProbe` if any of the worker nodes wants to request some work. If a request is available it is read with `comm.Receive` and the work is sent to the worker for processing.

When I run my test program with `mpiexec.exe` on a single host, either localhost or also a remote host everything works as expected, but when I run it on two hosts at the same time
the `Send` on the remote host blocks and the master nodes `ImmediateProbe` never receives the message sent from the worker on the remote host.

I run the program with `mpiexec.exe -wdir \\DESKTOP-58QONBS\MPITest -hosts 2 DESKTOP-58QONBS 2 LAPTOP-L8F7AN5R 1 MPITest.exe`

I'm new to MPI, so maybe I am doing something wrong I just could not figure out yet why the behaviour is like this when using two hosts at the same time.

The full code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace MPITest
{
    public abstract class MPIMasterWorkerBase<TWork, TResult>
        where TWork : class
        where TResult : class
    {
        protected abstract void Initialize(bool isMaster);
        protected abstract void Main();
        protected abstract void ProcessResult(TResult result);
        protected abstract TResult ProcessWork(TWork work);
        protected abstract TWork GetWork();

        private volatile bool terminate = false;
        private Thread thread;
        private MPI.Intracommunicator comm;

        public void Run(string[] args)
        {
            MPI.Environment.Run(ref args, comm =>
            {
                this.comm = comm;

                if (comm.Size < 2)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("At least 2 processes are required.");
                    return;
                }

                if (comm.Rank == 0)
                {
                    Initialize(isMaster: true);

                    thread = new Thread(MasterThread);
                    thread.Start();

                    Main();

                    terminate = true;
                    thread.Join();
                }
                else
                {
                    Initialize(isMaster: false);

                    thread = new Thread(WorkerThread);
                    thread.Start();
                    thread.Join();
                }
            });
        }

        private void MasterThread()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"MasterStart {MPI.Environment.ProcessorName}");

            var done = new bool[comm.Size];
            done[0] = true;

            while (!done.All(x => x == true))
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < comm.Size; i++)
                {
                    if (comm.ImmediateProbe(i, 0) != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Receive: {i}");
                        comm.Receive<int>(i, 0);

                        var work = GetWork();
                        if (work != null)
                        {
                            comm.Send(1, i, 0);
                            comm.Send(work, i, 0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (terminate)
                            {
                                comm.Send(-1, i, 0);
                                done[i] = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                comm.Send(0, i, 0);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (comm.ImmediateProbe(i, 1) != null)
                    {
                        var result = comm.Receive<TResult>(i, 1);
                        ProcessResult(result);
                    }
                }

                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("MasterStop");
        }

        private void WorkerThread()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"WorkerStart: {comm.Rank} {MPI.Environment.ProcessorName}");

            while (!terminate)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine($"Send: {comm.Rank}");
                comm.Send(0, 0, 0);
                var flag = comm.Receive<int>(0, 0);
                if (flag == -1)
                    break;
                else if (flag == 0)
                    continue;

                var work = comm.Receive<TWork>(0, 0);
                var result = ProcessWork(work);
                comm.Send(result, 0, 1);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"WorkerStop: {comm.Rank}");
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class WorkItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class MPITest : MPIMasterWorkerBase<WorkItem, WorkItem>
    {
        private ConcurrentQueue<WorkItem> queue = new();
        private int id;

        protected override void Initialize(bool isMaster)
        {

        }

        protected override void Main()
        {
            var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
            while ((DateTime.UtcNow - startTime).TotalSeconds < 10)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    queue.Enqueue(new WorkItem { Id = id++ });
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        protected override WorkItem GetWork()
        {
            if (queue.TryDequeue(out var result))
                return result;
            return null;
        }

        protected override WorkItem ProcessWork(WorkItem work)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Processing Work {work.Id}");
            return work;
        }

        protected override void ProcessResult(WorkItem result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Process Result {result.Id}");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new MPITest().Run(args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you written a simple program using `MPI_Get_processor_name` (or whatever its equivalent MPI.Net) and confirmed that it prints out the host names correctly?

Comment: Yes. I also updated the code to print the processor names. The master and one worker start on the localhost and one worker starts on the remote host.

Comment: I also checked the firewall but this should not be the problem as I allowed all connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `comm.Send` was blocking, but after some minutes of waiting the program started to work.

The issues were caused by the **VirtualBox Host-Only Network** Adapter that was also installed on the system. Disabling this adapter in the network settings resolved all the issues.